# Pinterest removing the media parameter

Tags: pinterest

I'm having a bad time trying to implement a simple PinIt button.

I followed all the process and it works fine, with an exception: it is removing the Media parameter from the anchor tag.
This means that the PinIt button will open a window showing all the images from that page and the user needs to select one.

The source is ok:

```
<a href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://www.tokstok.com.br/vitrine/produto.jsf?idItem=6920&amp;media=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tokstok.com.br%2Fpnv%2F570%2Fa%2Farmap166_nz.jpg&amp;description=ARMAZÉM APARADOR 166X37" data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-config="none" data-pin-color="white"><img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_fg_en_rect_white_20.png" /></a>
```

But, when the page is loaded, the pinit.js is replacing the parameters.

I have tried to find a solution on the web and read something about the URL Enconde, I have tried with UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 but without success.

The rendered html is:

```
<a href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tokstok.com.br%2Fvitrine%2Fproduto.jsf&amp;media=&amp;guid=dXY5RJyNEP47-0&amp;description=ARMAZ%C3%89M%20APARADOR%20166X37%20-%20Tok%26Stok" class="PIN_1395089773564_pin_it_button_20 PIN_1395089773564_pin_it_button_en_20_white PIN_1395089773564_pin_it_button_inline_20 PIN_1395089773564_pin_it_none_20" target="_blank" data-pin-log="button_pinit" data-pin-config="none"><span class="PIN_1395089773564_hidden" id="PIN_1395089773564_pin_count_0"><i></i></span></a>
```

The media parameter is there, empty.

Thanks for your time,
William Borgo.

Comment: Are you trying to pass the media parameter to //www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/, or include as part of the url parameter (It looks like you're doing the former, not the latter)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question, I just copy paste from the API reference...

Comment: The params is passed to the anchor href, following the pinterest.com/pin/create/button url.

Comment: What value are you trying to pass to the url parameter, in the link to //www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is actually in your url parameter. It cannot contain hashtags or other types of parameters. If you delete `?idItem=6920` from the url it will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your URL encoding is incorrect and is confusing Pinterest as to what is part of the Pinterest URL and what is part of one of the parameters - essentially where each parameter begins and ends, and what's a separate parameter for Pinterest vs a continuation of a previous parameter. (This is really the purpose of URL encoding for parameters.)

That is, the overall Pinterest URL should be like:

www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=[url]&media=[media]&description=[description]

The "&" separating the url, media, and description parameters should NOT be encoded. But each of the parameters themselves (the parts in [brackets]) SHOULD be encoded.

So for instance:

https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tokstok.com.br%2Fvitrine%2Fproduto.jsf%3FidItem%3D121826&media=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tokstok.com.br%2Fpnv%2F570%2Fc%2Fconnmlt_czbr1.jpg&description=CONNECTION%20MESA%20PARA%20LAPTOP

...which you could look at like this (with line breaks between parameters and some spacing):

```
https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/
    ?url         = http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tokstok.com.br%2Fvitrine%2Fproduto.jsf%3FidItem%3D121826
    &media       = http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tokstok.com.br%2Fpnv%2F570%2Fc%2Fconnmlt_czbr1.jpg
    &description = CONNECTION%20MESA%20PARA%20LAPTOP
```

(Note: the URL you gave seems not to be active any more, so I grabbed another product from the site.)